# How can I program a key detection system for a CLI app in C?

Tags: c

I want to do a complex to do CLI app in C, and I'm just asking how Vim or Mutt have a system to detect keys. And how can I have an input with enter and not have to write the whole screen again for having a newline.

I tried using `fgets` or `getchar`, but I don't want to have to press enter to some functions.
I don't want to use libraries like conio.

Comment: You have to use *some* OS function, or a library. The standard C and C++ console is buffered to support [the separate terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson#/media/File:Ken_Thompson_(sitting)_and_Dennis_Ritchie_at_PDP-11_(2876612463).jpg) used when C was designed.

Comment: Have you had a look at [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)? It's a terminal ui library used by applications like `htop`.

Comment: The `c++-cli` tag is not for command-line interfaces, it's one of the weirder dialects of C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, while the ideal solution would be to use a library like `curses` or `ncurses`, you can theoretically do it without a library by manipulating terminal implementation. Each terminal implementation will have somewhat different escape functions for things like positioning the cursor and things like that.

Although many of them will follow to some extent the ANSI escape codes, you will find A LOT of variation on that, and your program will have to implement each of them according to your `TERM` variable (on POSIX systems) or some other kind of indication (I don't know about Windows/DOS)

The ANSI code to position the cursor, for instance, would be CSI n ; m H[1]. So, to print something in the 25th col and the 25th line, your code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    char chr;
    printf("\033[25;25H");
    scanf("%c", &chr);
    printf("%c\n", chr);
    return 0;
}
```

It positions the cursor at the 25th col of the 25th line, and by keeping the terminal's echo enabled, whatever the user types will appear in that line. It also prints the key you insert and puts a line break. It works on my xterm-256color terminal and will likely work on most commonly used Linux terminals.

It might not work in a lot of terminals, though.

For that reason, IMHO it would be a nightmare to make your code work in a portable way - and by portable I mean across even different terminals on the same operating system, so using a library like `ncurses` to abstract all that escaping for you would be the less painful way of coding.

REFERENCES

[1] ANSI Escape codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#In_C